# Does time pass differently in Stormhold than it does in England?

Tags: stardust

In the 2007 film [**Stardust**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(2007_film)), protagonist Tristan has one week until Victoria's birthday in which to find the fallen star and return with it. By the time he ends up on Captain Shakespeare's airship, two days have already passed. And when they depart the airship, Yvaine states that Victoria's birthday is tomorrow. This means they were on the airship for four days, yet in that time the montage makes it seem that much more time passes. Enough, in fact, for Tristan to learn how to fence/swordfight quite well - something that even a fast learner would take months to do.

I know that Stardust is based on a [graphic novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(novel)) by the same name, and I also know that the movie differs quite a bit from the source material. However, since I haven't read it I wanted to ask the following two questions:

**Does this week-long timeframe exist in the novel? And if so, does time pass differently on the "faerie" side of the wall than on the "real" side?**

Comment: Stardust is not based on a graphic novel, it is based on an [illustrated novel](http://www.stardust-and-alchemy.com/stardust/books.html).

Comment: Can he really fence/swordfight that well? AFAIR the only evidence for his prowess is that he once touches Captain Shakespeare (who might have just let him do so, since they were in training), intimidates Humphrey (all that takes is looking fierce), and holds his own against zombie-Septimus (not too hard, since the latter's limbs are only moving under the influence of a voodoo doll).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original novel, substantially more time passes between Tristan setting off from the wall to the point at which he returns, some 13 weeks. That being said, in both versions he only seems to spend a few days on the *Perdita* with Captain Alberic/Captain Shakespeare.

### Does time pass at different rates?

**Film:**
Not obviously. Tristan is delivered to Dunstan as a newborn 9 months after his trip to the market. When Tristan travels back to Wall, only seven days pass; The night in the inn, four (?) nights on the Perdita, the night in the carriage and the night in the coaching inn.

How does he learn to swordfight so quickly? Captain Shakespeare is clearly an excellent teacher. The same way in which Yvaine learns to play the piano in a single night, obviously.

**Novel:**
Not obviously. Tristran leaves for the star in October. He describes the return journey as being around six months travel, obviously foreshortened by his journey on the Free Ship.

When he returns, Victoria is setting up for her wedding in the meadow by the wall. There's a few other contextual clues in the text that it's no longer winter but no explicit confirmation.